# Garbage collection of a sliced buffer

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, buffer

I have TCP based client/server application with server side on Node.js. Because TCP is a stream and I need separate packets I send two-byte length before every packet (common practice I guess). Big packets can come in few chunks (because of MTU and other things) so I need to extract every packet that I can from current buffer and leave the rest for joining with next incoming chunk and parsing again. I've come up with following code:

```
function parsePackets(data) {
    // join existing buffer contents with new chunk
    var buffer = Buffer.concat([this.buffer, data]);

    var start = 0;
    var end = buffer.length;

    var packets = [];

    while (true) {
        // wait for at least two bytes
        if (end - start < 2) {
            break;
        }

        var length = buffer.readUInt16BE(start);

        // wait until we can read whole packet
        if (end - start < length) {
            break;
        }

        // push packet data as a separate packet
        //var data = new Buffer(length);
        //buffer.copy(data, 0, start, start + length);
        var data = buffer.slice(start, start + length);
        packets.push(data);

        start += length;
    }

    // drop parsed buffer contents, leaving the rest
    //var newBuffer = new Buffer(buffer.length - start);
    //buffer.copy(newBuffer, 0, start, buffer.length);
    //this.buffer = newBuffer;
    this.buffer = buffer.slice(start, buffer.length);

    return packets;
}
```

My concern is: Will sliced off buffer contents be garbage collected? Also I'm doing `concat` that returns new buffer (I assume copying contents from provided buffers, which means they can be garbage collected). Or maybe I need to use `copy` instead of `slice` (I have an example in commented lines)?

I want performant code without memory leaks, so I dont want to copy data more than I should. But currently it looks like memory usage of my application just grow bigger and bigger (I don't know how to test it for sure and how to check if sliced off contents will be freed sometime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no accumulating leak of buffer objects in your code.

Any Buffer objects that you no longer retain a reference to in your code will be immediately available for garbage collection.  So, each time you call `parsePackets()`, you create several new buffer objects with `.concat()` and `.slice()`, but you only retain a reference to one buffer object each time in the `this.buffer` instance variable and each time that buffer is replaced with a new buffer (making the prior one eligible for garbage collection).

So, there is no build up or accumulating leak of buffer objects in this code.

---

For complete code cleanliness, you will want to make sure that when you've finished reading all your data, the last buffer object stored in `this.buffer` is nulled out with something like `this.buffer = null;` so no reference is retained to it even though processing is done.   That will not be necessary of the object holding this reference is itself cleaned up.

Comment: > finished reading all your data. what do you mean? there is always data to read as long as client is connected. and when client will disconnect this.buffer will be destroyed along with this.

Comment: @bobby - OK, then that part is fine.  You didn't show how the lifetime of the overall object was managed so I had no way of knowing how it was being used.

Answer (score 1):

In Buffer, there is nothing actually sliced off. With slice operation, a new view of the buffer is created which points to the new location and will have its own length. Modifying the original buffer, will modify the sliced buffer too.
As per your code, you'll create a new buffer only in Buffer.concat. After then you assign its several chunks into packets and rest into this.buffer. All these buffers will point to the original buffer created via concat method. This is the most memory efficient approach feasible, and it won't create any problem till no 2 chunks have an overlapping memory.